# How to only download files beginning with a certain range of numbers?

Tags: linux, terminal, download, wget

I'm trying to download files from a numbered list on a website.  The list goes up to 6179 items, but I want to start the download from item 4852.

I've tried the command:

```
wget -m -np -c -A "*[4852-6179]*" "WEBSITE"
```

However that starts the download from item 1 for some reason.

The command:

```
wget -m -np -c -A "*485[2-9]*" "WEBSITE"
```

Works perfectly, but it only downloads files 4852-4859.  How can I increase that range to 4852-6179?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that starts the download from item 1 for some reason

The reason is `[...]` specifies possible characters, not numbers; and it matches a single character. It works with one-digit numbers because a single digit is a character. `[4852-6179]` is equivalent to  `[48523456179]` equivalent to `[123456789]` equivalent to `[1-9]`, it matches any digit but `0`.

> `485[2-9]`
>
> Works perfectly, but it only downloads files 4852-4859. How can I increase that range to 4852-6179?

Using multiple patterns one by one is quite straightforward:

```
485[2-9]          # 4852-4859
48[6-9][0-9]      # 4860-4899
49[0-9][0-9]      # 4900-4999
5[0-9][0-9][0-9]  # 5000-5999
60[0-9][0-9]      # 6000-6099
61[0-7][0-9]      # 6100-6179
```